# Angular Directive - create new binding for two way and "pass by value"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

This is an extension of a previous question (and similar questions) in which I asked if it was possible to have an attribute on a directive allow a value to be passed like these.

```
<my-directive att>                //Evaluates to true
<my-directive att="true">        
<my-directive att="false">
<my-directive att="51">
<my-directive att="51.234">
<my-directive att="'john smith'">
```

or, could use two way binding to a variable on the scope like this.

```
<my-directive att="SomeVariableOnControllerScope">
```

Now, this won't work with the standard "=" two way binding. I've tried various attempts but whenever you try to change something inside your directive it tries to write it back to the variable and if it's not a proper variable you get the standard "non assignable" error.

But, somebody alluded to the fact that it would be possible to create a new type of binding. In theory this new type of binding could look at the value passed in to see if it was a boolean, integer, float, or a string in single quotes. If it was it could use that and "switch off" two way binding so nothing ever gets written back. If the value is none of those passed then it would do exactly as = does and set up two way binding.

I have no idea how to go about this but may be able to work it out if given a shove in the right direction. The value in this is that we often need to output HTML from the server (for SEO reasons) which sets a value and often don't need to bind with something in a controller. However sometimes 2 way binding IS needed.

So, basically what I'm looking for is a hybrid @ and = binding which intelligently knows whether a value or variable name is being passed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather you can use **@ operator**  and pass an extra attribute for datatype. You can then cast the value to desired datatype inside directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ $parse service is able to parse a value and tell if it's a constant or not

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

2/ This is the code used on isolated scopes for dual way scope bindings :

```
        var dataBind = function(parentScopeName, scopeName, childScope, parentScope) {
        if(parentScope == null) {
            parentScope = childScope.$parent;
        }
        var parentGet = $parse(parentScopeName);
        var compare = parentGet.literal ? angular.equals : function(a,b) { return a === b; };
        var lastValue;

        var parentSet = parentGet.assign || function() {
            // reset the change, or we will throw this exception on every $digest
            lastValue = childScope[scopeName] = parentGet(parentScope);
            throw "didnt understand this exception";
        };
        lastValue = childScope[scopeName] = parentGet(parentScope);
        return childScope.$watch(function parentValueWatch() {
            var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);
            if (!compare(parentValue, childScope[scopeName])) {
                // we are out of sync and need to copy
                if (!compare(parentValue, lastValue)) {
                    // parent changed and it has precedence
                    childScope[scopeName] = parentValue;
                } else {
                    // if the parent can be assigned then do so
                    parentSet(parentScope, parentValue = childScope[scopeName]);
                }
            }
            return (lastValue = parentValue);
        }, null, parentGet.literal);
    }
```

So you can do what you want with a combination of this method and the $parse service (you wont be able to use isolated scope '=' or '@' though):

```
var parsed = $parse($attrs.myAttribute);
if(parsed.constant) {
     $scope.whereIWantMyConstantInChildScope = parsed();
} else {
     dataBind($attrs.myAttribute, "whereIWantMyConstantInChildScope", $scope); // 4rth param is optional, will fallback to parent scope.
}
```

This is the technical solution.

However, I think the best practice would be to handle these two cases ( constant vs binding ) with two differents attributes, (as there are basically very different needs and wanting to merge the two behaviors looks pretty much like lazyness-driven-development), and an if/else in your isolated-scope directive linking. This would avoid all this useless code overheat...

Comment: I kind of agree with the last statement, although it's not driven by laziness, it's driven by a desire to give users of my framework the flexibility to do either without having two version of each attribute. e.g. a map directive with attributes draggable="true", latitude="51.3489" longitude="0.1246" would also need the following attributes - draggable-model="myScope.draggable" latitude-model="myScope.latitude" etc. This doesn't seem very DRY when you have lots of attributes, setting up double the bindings, double the watches etc. It seems messy, but then this new "hybrid" binding  seems hacky.

Comment: Wont double the watchs if automated with basic logic (example my-attr -> watch, my-attr-static -> constant) and handled in linking (this is not more than what angular does in isolated directive linkage, and it's easy to factorize into an util) But it does mean dropping of all usages of isolated scopes ( but it's not an issue IMHO, dropping isolated scope usages is the first necessary step of undestanding how angular really works and how you can optimize stuff... )